# Injective integer polynomial is injective modulo some prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Let $Q\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a polynomial defining an injective function $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$. Does it define an injective function $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for some prime $p$?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Consider $Q(x)=x(2x-1)(3x-1)$. This gives an injective map $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$, because $n<m \implies Q(n)<Q(m)$. However, this $Q$ is not injective over $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ for any $p$ because $Q(x)=0$ has three solutions when $p\geq 5$ and two solutions when $p\in \{2,3\}$.

Answer (score 21):

While the original question has been answered, there is a beautiful result of Fried in [On a conjecture of Schur](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1029000374) which is relevant to such questions.  Suppose $Q$ is a polynomial in ${\Bbb Q}[x]$ such that for infinitely many primes the induced map from ${\Bbb Z}/p{\Bbb Z}$ to ${\Bbb Z}/p{\Bbb Z}$ is bijective.  Then $Q$ must be of the form

(i) $Q(x) = ax^n + b$,

or

(ii) $Q(x) = T_n(x)$, where $T_n(x)$ denotes the $n$-th Chebyshev polynomial,

or

(iii) Compositions of functions of this type.

This established an old conjecture of Schur. See also the account [Turnwald - On Schur's conjecture](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c50c/b6d83238eeeab078b518db8c79dbf242fdc6.pdf?_ga=2.22479677.788452893.1597002164-1326647130.1595729845), which discusses the history of the problem, and gives a detailed proof, correcting inaccuracies in the earlier literature.

Comment: how does a polynomial with rational coefficients induce a map $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Just take the primes not dividing denominators of coefficients and reduce.

Comment: That is to say, part of the quantification is "for infinitely many primes $p$, *there is an induced self-map of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and* it is bijective".  (Of course, the first condition throws away only finitely many primes.)